# Action script for Enter button event of entire focused elements in a project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

Hi I'am developing an Adobe AIR application.I have implemented click event for all the buttons in my project.Now I want to add the "ENTER" keyboard events for the focused buttons..Are there any easy ways to achieve it? Please advice me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this kind of things :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       addedToStage="addEnterFeature()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function addEnterFeature() : void
            {
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
                myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
            }

            private function onKeyDown(e : KeyboardEvent) : void
            {
                if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER && stage.focus is Button)
                    // Simulate a mouse click on current focused button
                    Button(stage.focus).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
            }

            private function onButtonClick(e : Event) : void
            {
                trace("Button click handler");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button label="Test" id="myButton" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

It will simulate a mouse click if you use Enter on every buttons in your app (that have focus)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I ll implement and let you know.
I have more than 50 mxml files in my project,Do I need to implement this to all mxml?

Comment: You juste have to run this code once in your app. Because it's not linked to UI but to stage.